# Why do ActiveRecord callbacks require instance variables or instance methods to be prefixed with self keyword?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

ActiveRecord has a few different callback methods used to simplify model logic. For example `after_find` and `before_create` methods.

Consider this code example:

```
class ExternalPrintingCard < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :ph_user

  after_create :change_pin

  def change_pin
    self.user.randomize_printer_pin
  end

  def after_find
    return if self.card_status == false
    self.card_status = false if self.is_used_up?
    self.card_status = false if self.is_expired?
    self.save!
  end
end
```

If I remove all the `self` prefixes from the instance variables or instance methods, these 2 callbacks will be called, but it is as if they are local variables inside these callback methods.

This instance variable (`card_status`), instance methods (`save!`, `is_used_up?` and `is_expired?`) and association (`user`) worked fine outside these 2 callback methods without the `self` prefix.

The sample code in the Rails' documentation for callback methods (instance methods), seems to always use the `self` prefix even though it is calling instance variables or methods, which by right they are accessible without the `self` prefix normally.

I hope someone with a better understanding of ActiveRecord callbacks can help to shed a light on this behaviour.

Cheers

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Technically you only need to use the self in front of the assignment methods.
This is necessary to differentiate between a instance method with trailing = and an assignment to a local variable.

Comment: See this Thoughtbot article for many details: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/185504560/to-self-or-not-to-self

Answer (score 5):

Nasmorn is correct.

ActiveRecord::Base placed all the column names inside `@attributes` instance variable (Hash) and create accessors instance methods for those column names.

For example:

card_status is a column in external_printing_cards table, it will have accessor methods with the name `card_status` and `card_status=`

Since ruby local variable definition is dynamic, the line

```
def after_find
  ....  
  card_status = false if self.is_used_up?
  ....
end
```

will mean we are defining and assigning to a local variable `card_status` rather than the instance method `card_status=`

The article that Peer Allan posted provides more explanation on this.