# self vs non-self in instance method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, self

Why the first code (with **self**) works but the second doesn't?
*`category_uri` is the attribute of model*

```
def set_uri
  self.category_uri = self.category_uri.join('-').downcase
  self.save!
end
```

Without **self**

```
def set_uri
  category_uri = category_uri.join('-').downcase
  save!
end
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496380/why-do-activerecord-callbacks-require-instance-variables-or-instance-methods-to?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

In second case, interpreter treats `category_uri = ...` as local variable assignment. That's why if you want to call setter method (the one with trailing `=`), you have to use `self`.

Comment: But if I call ```category_uri``` in method I'll get the category_uri value

Comment: @freemanoid yes, because if there's no local variable `category_uri` set, it's treated as method call with implicit receiver `self`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def set_uri
  self.category_uri = self.category_uri.join('-').downcase
  self.save!
end
```

The method 'set_uri' will get called like: instance.set_uri, so in this case 'self' is set to the instance which calls the method.
But in the second code without 'self', 'category_uri' is actually treated as a local variable.
In fact Ruby will inexplicitly set 'self' to be the method itself, rather than the instance calling it in this case, so it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Marek has already said the reason why the second not working.

The two pieces of code are all not good at this purpose of manipulating attributes. Better to use `write_attribute` to eliminate the confuse.

My suggestion of refactoring

```
def set_uri
  write_attribute(:category_uri, category_uri.join('-').downcase)
  save!
end
```

Comment: Is there any other reason to use write_attribute beside disambiguation? Because `self.category_uri = value` is a lot shorter than `write_attribute(:category_uri, value)`

Comment: @JamesMcMahon, disambiguation is my main purpose. Also I prefer not to use `self` in instance method though that's only a personal taste.