# Remove only emoticons from string in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, emoticons

A user is using an emoticon and it is erroring out my app. How can I get check if the string contains an emoticon and remove only the emoticon?

```
 Message.create(user: @user, ticket: @ticket, text: "\r\nIm done with this bug! \u{1f431}!\r\n")

 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Incorrect string value: 'x90\xB1!\x0D
```

Comment: You might find [this](http://andy-carter.com/blog/saving-emoticons-unicode-from-twitter-to-a-mysql-database) helpful.

Comment: Thanks Cary! I cant alter my mysql table at this time. Or else that would be the solution I would implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is occuring because your database doesnt allow for utf8mb4 so you need to check for both and return the text. I would do the check as a callback and only if the text field has changed in order to reduce the number of times the callback is called.

```
 before_save :ensure_utf8, if: :text_changed?

def ensure_utf8
   if self.text
      self.text = self.text.encode( Encoding.find('UTF-8'), { invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '' } )
      self.text = self.text.each_char.select { |c| c.bytes.first < 240 }.join('')
   end
end
```

Comment: 1. What is the significance of `240` (and not `255`, for example)? 2. You need to open the class in which `ensure_utf8` is defined. 3. You do not need any of those `self.`'s.

Comment: The emoticon bytes start at 240, not 255. Also you need the self. to work with the callback.

Comment: John, you may have to humour me, as I don't know Rails. If you define any method outside a class, as you have done, `self.class => Object`. I assume that's not what you mean, that `ensure_utf8` is defined within some other class (e.g., `class String; def ensure_utf8; ...; end; end`). I'm asking you to show the class. `self.` is normally not required within a method definition, because the receiver defaults to `self` in the absense of an explicit receiver (e.g, `class String; def size_squared; size**2; end; end; 'cat'.size_squared #=> 9`. So why is `self.` required?

Comment: Cary, youre totally right in your thinking. I had to check my code to make sure you needed the self. Here is a link that may explain it better than me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496380/why-do-activerecord-callbacks-require-instance-variables-or-instance-methods-to

Comment: `#ensure_utf8` is not being defined outside of a class, it is (presumably) defined in a Rails model. `self` thus refers to an instance of the model. The use of `self` is actually need only for the assignment statement, to distinguish between a local variable assignment (`foo = "bar"`) and the attribute writer method `foo=`, or in other words, `self.send(:foo=, "bar")`.

Comment: It should also be pointed out that leaving off `self` when using an attribute writer method is guaranteed to trip up every Rails developer at least once. Sometimes more than once, if you are the forgetful type...

Comment: @zetetic, good explanation. It's perhaps worth adding that if `self` is dropped in an assignment when there's a setter method, the value is assigned to a local variable. There is another situation (and others that I cannot recall at the moment) when `self.` is needed: when one wants to fetch the instance's class: `self.class`. That's because `class` is also a keyword (though I confess I don't know why Ruby can't figure out what's wanted if `self.` were omitted).

Comment: John, it was just happenstance that I saw your comment directed to me. For me to be notified by SO, you need to include @CarySwoveland (or just @Cary).